# Having troubles with url-rewriting using .htaccess on wamp server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite the url of a certain php file.

Aim for url: `www.mysite.com/filename/topic/` or `www.mysite.com/filename/topic`

What works: `www.mysite.com/filename` and `www.mysite.com/topic`

I've tried all rewrite rules I know which should work, but every time I add the topic to the url I end up with a `500 internal server error`

Current .htacces file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

//No need for php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

//Rewriting the url
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ filename.php?topic=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ filename.php?topic=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have conflicting rules and there is probably an issue with content negotiation with MultiViews. Also you aren't using all the flags ([L]) need to prevent continuation of rules matching.

You can't do it that way with the second set of rules and you don't need 2 rules just to have a `/` or not. You can make it optional. You need to do something like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?topic=$2 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer. It works somewhat, only problem i end up with is that my css/jquery ain't loading correctly when adding `.com/filename/topic`. even though i'm grabbing from the root. `/css/style.css`